# Why the Flask teardown_request can not get exception object under debug mode (always None, but normal when debug=True)?

Tags: python, flask

I want to rollback my `db` session while exception happens, so I tried:

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
    print "Teardown 1 {0!r}".format(exception)
    if exception:
        print ">>>> Exception Happaned <<<<"
        db.session.rollback()
        db.session.remove()
    print "good"
    db.session.remove()
```

I tested to raise an exception by forcing my code to error, even using this:

```
raise Exception("bacoff")
```

But it always print `"Teardown 1 None"` and `"good"`.

**What confused me is once I close the DEBUG mode by `app.run(debug=False)`, 
the exception shows right:**

```
Teardown 1 Exception('bacoff',)
>>>> Exception Happaned <<<<
good
```

so, I don't know is this a bug of Flask framework, or my configuration fault...

My ENV is:

- BeautifulSoup 3.2.1
- Flask 0.9
- Flask-Login 0.1.3
- Flask-Mail 0.8.2
- Flask-OpenID 1.1.1
- Flask-SQLAlchemy 0.16
- Flask-WTF 0.8.3
- Flask-WhooshAlchemy 0.55a
- Jinja2 2.6
- SQLAlchemy 0.8.1
- Tempita 0.5.1
- WTForms 1.0.3
- Werkzeug 0.8.3
- Whoosh 2.4.1
- blinker 1.2
- decorator 3.4.0
- lxml 3.2.0
- pycurl 7.19.0
- python-openid 2.2.5
- requests 1.2.0
- sqlalchemy-migrate 0.7.2
- wsgiref 0.1.2

Comment: teardown_request has nothing to do with exceptions : http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request

Comment: The document says "When a teardown function was called because of a exception it will be passed an error object.", so I think once a exception raised it will passed to the teardown_request function, am I right? Beside, I can get the exception when DEBUG=True mode. These make me confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally resolved it by adding

> app.config['PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION'] = False

the solution comes from http://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/661#issuecomment-11975645 .

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`dispatch_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.dispatch_request) and [`full_dispatch_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.full_dispatch_request): first call your view, second catch your view exception. Simply you can override `dispatch_request` with yours error handlers, but `Flask` provided special mechanism for this: [`error_handler_spec`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.error_handler_spec).
So you can use [`errorhandler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.errorhandler) or [`register_error_handler`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.register_error_handler) to register handler to catch your exceptions.

```
@app.errorhandler(YourException)
def your_exception_handler(exception):
    print ">>>> Exception Happaned <<<<"
    db.session.rollback()
    return 'something wrong', 400

@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(*args, **kwargs):
    print "good"
    db.session.remove()
```

Comment: It seems need to specific exception class in you solution, I want to rollback the db session in any Exception....Thanks tbicr.

Comment: You can use `Exception` class but in this case any HTTPException (http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/exceptions/#werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException) will handled by default anyway. I don't think that using `Exception` handler best solution (you always can handle specific exceptions), but it's can be need for your case. Better look at the code: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L1468, you always can override `dispatch_request` or `handle_user_exception` for your case.

Comment: Thanks for your help, tbicr.I finally resolved it by adding "app.config['PRESERVE_CONTEXT_ON_EXCEPTION'] = False", the solution comes from https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/issues/661#issuecomment-11975645 . Thank you.